# Login script - counting rows or using COUNT('column')

Tags: php, mysql

I've been dabbling abit with a login script (PHP and MySQL), using various online tutorials. Today I became curious as to which way is the best to check if a username and password is valid. Every tutorial I've read so far checks the number of row returned, like this:

```
SELECT stuff FROM users WHERE username = input_username AND password = input_password
count the rows returned
if rows equal to one
login
else
display error message
```

I was just thinking if it's equally viable to use COUNT and check that value instead, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(stuff) FROM users WHERE username = input_username AND password = input_password
if returned value equal to one
login
else
display error message
```

I've tried both and both work return the intended result. So is there any reason to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely go with second SQL-statement if you don't need any of the information stored. `COUNT()` is better for performance. Although the reason people tend to stick to the first one is because they will be needing information about the user if rows returned is positive.

Comment: Assuming he has a UNIQUE constraint on the username field, I doubt very much COUNT() would be faster. It's just an index lookup in both cases.

Comment: @Artefact2 the performance difference isn't large in this case but it would be a slight difference in execution time if benchmarked.

Answer (score 3):

They are both valid approaches. You would use the former when you needed additional info about the user, e.g., their UserID.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much to. Right now I'm using the "row-method" when logging in and the "count-method" when the user wants to change password.